# Bulma content going outside of box

Tags: css, bulma

I'm trying to make a website with Bulma, but I have run into this problem.

I'm trying to have a box with customizable content inside, but the content keeps going outside of the box.

Here's my simple code:

```
<p class="box center" style="width: 1000px; text-align: center;">content</p>
```

and my result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llVx4.png).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Remove the inline style - width: `1000px` ??

Comment: @sol What do you mean by inline style?

Comment: In your HTML, inside the `<p>` element, you have a style rule, declaring the width of the paragraph to be `1000px`.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your text in a div with a class of "box". That should do the trick. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldi/togbyh24/4/)

```
<div class="column is-6 is-offset-3">
  <div class="box">
    <p class="title is-4">Your long text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is title class not box that wraps the text in a container

```
<p class="title is-6">Your long text here</p>
```

and is-6 makes it good enough to read in Desktop